# Is it true that no other country provides subsidies for gas and power?

Tags: energy-policy, subsidies

Bangladeshi PM said the following on Jan 18th 2023:

- [Hasina says industries must pay for uninterrupted supply as govt explains gas price hike](https://bdnews24.com/economy/b52g7p66vq)

> She then questioned subsidies for gas and power. “No other country gives subsidies for gas and power.”

- [Buy gas at global price, get smooth supply](https://www.thedailystar.net/news/bangladesh/news/buy-gas-global-price-get-smooth-supply-3224761)

> Hasina said the government is giving subsidy to power and gas. "My question is that which country in the world provides subsidy to electricity and gas. No country gives subsidy to them. We've increased the electricity generation and ensured its supply. But all will have to exercise austerity in using electricity."

Is this statement of hers true; that is, does no country on earth subsidize industrial or household energy consumption?

Answers with references would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes there are countries that do this and what value would be in a listing of all of?

Comment: This is very broad. Most European countries have some kind of support at least for poor people, some for everyone. The rationales differ.

Comment: Most introduced additional subsidies in the last year to avoid large fractions of the population to become unable to pay their bills due to the sudden increase in energy prices. The specific implementaions and the rationales for them differ considerably, though.

Comment: Most also subsidize energy-intensive industry, such as aluminium, steel and chemical production, IT and other infrastructure etc. for strategic reasons, to varying degrees.

Comment: This question seems to have a massive edit after an answer was provided and it does not say what country it is referring to after the edit.

Comment: @JoeW, The answer is still on-point.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, the UK for example.

> The government will give every household £400 off their electricity bill. This is called the Energy Bills Support Scheme.

There are other subsidies that are means-tested (paid to poorer people) or age-related (paid to older people).  There are specific subsidies for particular energy sources (for example tax reductions on heat pump installations)